# Set default style to table in ASP.Net

Tags: css, html-table

My asp.net theme has default css style. How can I set default style to all my `<td>` in this css style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do somthing like below to apply default style to all table element

```
table
{
border-collapse:collapse;
}
table,th, td
{
border: 1px solid black;
}
```